# Hadoop 2.6.0 eclipse plugin

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

Can anybody share step by step guide for how to download and set up eclipse plugin for Hadoop 2.6.0 version.i am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Download and build this project https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin

$ cd src/contrib/eclipse-plugin

Assume hadoop installation directory is /usr/hdp

$ ant jar -Dversion=2.4.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.1 -Declipse.home=/opt/eclipse -Dhadoop.home=/usr/hdp

Your jar will be build in this directory only.

${hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin}/build/contrib/eclipse-plugin/hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.6.0.jar

Then close your eclipse and run it in clean mode. You will able to run your MR job through eclipse itself.